# access several folder for list.files

Tags: r

I am trying to access data in several folders. Let's say I have data that I want in 2 folders with the structure:

D:/local data/test/folderA/class.a/subfolderC/subclass.b/subfolderE/gotit

D:/local data/test/folderB/class.a/subfolderD/subclass.b/subfolderF/gotit

I have many other folders (different classes and subclasses that I do not want data from). Is there a way to get all the data from those specific folders? something like:

`files = list.files(path = "D:/local data/test/*./class.a/*./subclass.b/*./gotit", full.names = T,  pattern = "*.nc")`

This is a simplified example but in reality I have hundreds of folders and thousands of files so I can't write all the names.

Comment: Note that `pattern=` takes a regular expression, not a file glob. The `path=` needs to be. valid starting path. If you just use `path="D:/local data/test/"` with `recursive=TRUE` it will check all sub folders. Then use the correct regular expression to filter for the files you want.

Comment: `Sys.glob("D:/local data/test/*./class.a/*./subclass.b/*./gotit") |> grep("\\.nc$", x = _, value = TRUE)` might work (R-4.2 to use the `_` special placeholder there, `gsub("nc$", Sys.glob(...), value=TRUE)` works too)

Answer (score 0):

as r2evans sugested `Sys.glob` was the answer

```
files = Sys.glob("D:/local data/test/*/class.a/*/subclass.b/*/gotit/*.nc")
```

gets me all the files I need